# python lambda function with if statement

Tags: python, lambda

Can Any one correct it I kinda liked it but it's not working

```
f=lambda x:"Not Weird" if (x%2==0 and (1<x<6 or x>20)) else "weird"
print(f)
```

And I know I can do it with If else statement easily but it's just for learning purpose and so if you can improvise in the same direction then please enlighten me.

Comment: A lambda is like a function, you need to call it with `f(...)` for it to produce anything meaningful

Comment: Try `print(f(10))`

Comment: I know it's just for learning, but just to mention it's against PEP8 recommendations - _Always use a `def` statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a `lambda` expression directly to an identifier_

Comment: You failed to ask a question... What is wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fire`  the lambda using `()`

```
f=lambda x:"Not Weird" if (x%2==0 and (1<x<6 or x>20)) else "weird"
print(f(1))
```

```
weird
```

Comment: it's working great but for f(18) I am getting a "Not weird" print

Comment: `Fire`? Did you mean *call*?

Comment: @tripleee exactly the reason it's surprising... The problem is that it's not true. I get `weird` for `f(18)`

Comment: Yes, I just exaggerated it :p

Comment: @Tomerikoo I also got weird on my notebook but not on hackerrank I'm getting a failed test case for f(18) and f(20) expected o/p is weird